# How to generate 'ǂ' symbol in Latex

Tags: symbols

Can anyone let me know how to generate 'ǂ' in LaTeX?

I have tired the following segment but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\pipesymbol}{ǂ}
\begin{document}
The pipe symbol: \pipesymbol
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do learn how to use the free [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) utility. You may decide that the solution lies in loading the [tipa](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package and typing `\textdoublebarpipe`.

Comment: Or you can use "ǂ" asis using xelatex\lualatex and some  TTF or OTF font with the glyph (e.g., Symbola).  Note that wwith a wrong fontthe symbol will be exported to a white space, a box, a "?" symbol or whatever.